# How to remove rows with characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a bunch of floats and numeric values but there are some rows with characters mixed inbetween that I'm trying to remove. I've converted my entire dataframe to strings with `data = data.astype(str)` and I've tried using `X = X[X.var1.isalpha()]` but it gives me an error `'Series' object has no attribute 'isalpha'`. Thanks.

Comment: please share source data and expected output. It will help address the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','x',2,7], 'b':[2,3,'y',8]})

#   a  b
#0  1  2
#1  x  3
#2  2  y
#3  7  8

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = "coerce").dropna()
#     a    b
#0  1.0  2.0
#3  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: Yes something like that is good, I should've put an input and output but I'm very new to stackoverflow and not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isalpha.html) you need to call .str on the series you want to check, i.e.

```
X.var1.str.isalpha()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.str.replace`, which accepts `regex`, i.e.:

```
new = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[a-zA-Z]+', '')).astype(float)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work (the `astype` part). Also, OP is asking to remove rows, not chars

Comment: What's wrong with `astype`? Good point on the rows though.

Comment: You'll have some empty string (`''`) which will give an error while casting to float. It would be something like `float('')`